# How to group by range of dates Without UNION

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, range, union

I have this T-SQL query (SQL2012), `@START`and `@END` are previously defined.

```
DECLARE @WEEK SMALLINT
SET @WEEK = 7

WHILE @WEEK >= 0
BEGIN  

    SELECT @START= (SELECT DATEADD( wk, -1, @START ) ) 
    SELECT @END  = (SELECT DATEADD( wk, -1, @END   ) ) 

    SELECT
        Visits.idPatient,
        Visits.VDay,
        tblScheduledOrder.SDay
    FROM
        tblScheduledOrder
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                DATEPART( dw, VDate ) - 1 AS VDay,
                idPatient
            FROM
                tblVisits
            WHERE
                ( VDate >= @START ) AND
                ( VDate <= @END )
        ) AS Visits
            ON tblScheduledOrder.idPatient = Visits.idPatient 

    SELECT @WEEK = @WEEK - 1
END
```

There is a table for the "Scheduled Visit" of the patients (the patient schedule is everyweek, i.e. the visit should be done each Monday). The `tblScheduledVisit` consists of 2 fields (`tblScheduledOrder.idPatient` and `tblScheduledOrder.SDay`).

The actual visits, are stored in `tblVisits` which has (`tblVisits.VDate`, `tblVisits.idPatient`)

I need to provide a list of the past 8 weeks from the Patients, and the relation between their scheduled day and the real day they came.

As you can see, I do several Selects and then I make a union in the application, which is not the right way to do it, right?

```
--tblScheduledOrder--   ----tblVisits--------
|SDay   idPatient   |   |idPatient   VDate  | DATEPART(dw)
| 1       11        |   |11    #2018-3-18#  | 1
| 2       12        |   |12    #2018-3-19#  | 2
| 2       13        |   |13    #2018-3-20#  | 3
| 3       14        |   |14    #2018-3-20#  | 3
| 4       15        |   |15    #2018-3-21#  | 4
| 4       16        |   |16    #2018-3-22#  | 5
---------------------   |11    #2018-3-25#  | 1
                        |12    #2018-3-26#  | 2
                        |13    #2018-3-27#  | 3
                        |15    #2018-3-29#  | 5
                        |16    #2018-3-29#  | 5
                        ---------------------
```

Actual result

```
--First resultset-----
|idPati SDay    VDay |
|11     1       1    |
|12     2       2    |
|13     2       3    |
|14     3       3    |
|15     4       4    |
|16     4       5    |
--Second resulset-----
|11     1       1    |
|12     2       2    |
|13     2       3    |
|14     3       NULL |
|15     4       5    |
|16     4       5    |
----------------------
```

Required result

```
--Single resultset-----
|idPati SDay    VDay |
|11     1       1    |
|12     2       2    |
|13     2       3    |
|14     3       3    |
|15     4       4    |
|16     4       5    |
|11     1       1    |
|12     2       2    |
|13     2       3    |
|14     3       NULL |
|15     4       5    |
|16     4       5    |
----------------------
```

Comment: please provide sample data and desired result. `group by` to aggregate values but looking at your requirement you are display all the visits along with the actual visit date

Comment: @maSTAShuFu Yes, the output is the scheduled day, along with the actual visits.

Comment: go to `sqlfiddle.com` or `rextester.com` and muck up your data.

Comment: I think rather than coming up with awkward way to bend the data, you should store data in a way that would fit your usage. Either start storing null entry in tblVisits when patient didn't visit that week, or storing actual date for every patient every week in tblScheduledOrder. If those data were stored, you could do this query with a simple JOIN

Comment: @JackyCheng Well that is right, but that requires some app doing the INSERT on the table every week. And there are 15k patients, so I am guessing is only wasted space... Maybe I will reconsider it for a future version. Nowadays it needs to be solved the way it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I attempted a solution, but wasn't able to reconcile my results to the question and stopped. Perhaps someone else can take it further. see this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f485d/1)

```
CREATE TABLE tblScheduledOrder
    (SDay int, idPatient int)
;

INSERT INTO tblScheduledOrder
    (SDay, idPatient)
VALUES
    (1, 11),
    (2, 12),
    (2, 13),
    (3, 14),
    (4, 15),
    (4, 16)
;


CREATE TABLE tblVisits
    (idPatient int, VDate date)
;

INSERT INTO tblVisits
    (idPatient, VDate)
VALUES
    (11, '2018-03-18'),
    (12, '2018-03-19'),
    (13, '2018-03-20'),
    (14, '2018-03-20'),
    (15, '2018-03-21'),
    (16, '2018-03-22'),
    (11, '2018-03-25'),
    (12, '2018-03-26'),
    (13, '2018-03-27'),
    (15, '2018-03-29'),
    (16, '2018-03-29')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
declare @end as date
-- calculate "next" Monday
set @end = dateadd(d,-(datediff(d,0,getdate()) % 7)+7 ,cast(getdate() as date))
declare @start as date
set @start = dateadd(wk,-8,@end)
;with drange as (
  select @start as dt, datepart(dw,@start) dw
  union all
  select dateadd(d,1,dt) , datepart(dw,dateadd(d,1,dt))
  from drange
  where dateadd(d,1,dt) <= @end
  )
, p as (
  select 
         SDay
       , idPatient
       , dateadd(d,SDay-1,dateadd(d,-datediff(d,0,getdate()) % 7,cast(getdate() as date))) Ndate
  from tblScheduledOrder
  )  
select 
     dt, dw, p.Sday, vdate, ndate, coalesce(v.idpatient,p.idPatient) idpatient
from drange
left join tblVisits v on drange.dt = v.Vdate
left join p on drange.dt = p.Ndate
where drange.dw between 1 and 5
order by dt DESC, coalesce(v.idpatient,p.idPatient)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f485d/1/0)**:

```
|         dt | dw |   Sday |      vdate |      ndate | idpatient |
|------------|----|--------|------------|------------|-----------|
| 2018-04-02 |  2 | (null) |     (null) |     (null) |    (null) |
| 2018-04-01 |  1 | (null) |     (null) |     (null) |    (null) |
| 2018-03-29 |  5 |      4 | 2018-03-29 | 2018-03-29 |        15 |
| 2018-03-29 |  5 |      4 | 2018-03-29 | 2018-03-29 |        15 |
| 2018-03-29 |  5 |      4 | 2018-03-29 | 2018-03-29 |        16 |
| 2018-03-29 |  5 |      4 | 2018-03-29 | 2018-03-29 |        16 |
| 2018-03-28 |  4 |      3 |     (null) | 2018-03-28 |        14 |
| 2018-03-27 |  3 |      2 | 2018-03-27 | 2018-03-27 |        13 |
| 2018-03-27 |  3 |      2 | 2018-03-27 | 2018-03-27 |        13 |
| 2018-03-26 |  2 |      1 | 2018-03-26 | 2018-03-26 |        12 |
| 2018-03-25 |  1 | (null) | 2018-03-25 |     (null) |        11 |
| 2018-03-22 |  5 | (null) | 2018-03-22 |     (null) |        16 |
| 2018-03-21 |  4 | (null) | 2018-03-21 |     (null) |        15 |
| 2018-03-20 |  3 | (null) | 2018-03-20 |     (null) |        13 |
| 2018-03-20 |  3 | (null) | 2018-03-20 |     (null) |        14 |
| 2018-03-19 |  2 | (null) | 2018-03-19 |     (null) |        12 |
| 2018-03-18 |  1 | (null) | 2018-03-18 |     (null) |        11 |
| 2018-03-15 |  5 | (null) |     (null) |     (null) |    (null) |
| 2018-03-14 |  4 | (null) |     (null) |     (null) |    (null) |
| 2018-03-13 |  3 | (null) |     (null) |     (null) |    (null) |
| 2018-03-12 |  2 | (null) |     (null) |     (null) |    (null) |
| 2018-03-11 |  1 | (null) |     (null) |     (null) |    (null) |
| 2018-03-08 |  5 | (null) |     (null) |     (null) |    (null) |
| 2018-03-07 |  4 | (null) |     (null) |     (null) |    (null) |
| 2018-03-06 |  3 | (null) |     (null) |     (null) |    (null) |
| 2018-03-05 |  2 | (null) |     (null) |     (null) |    (null) |
| 2018-03-04 |  1 | (null) |     (null) |     (null) |    (null) |
| 2018-03-01 |  5 | (null) |     (null) |     (null) |    (null) |
| 2018-02-28 |  4 | (null) |     (null) |     (null) |    (null) |
| 2018-02-27 |  3 | (null) |     (null) |     (null) |    (null) |
| 2018-02-26 |  2 | (null) |     (null) |     (null) |    (null) |
| 2018-02-25 |  1 | (null) |     (null) |     (null) |    (null) |
| 2018-02-22 |  5 | (null) |     (null) |     (null) |    (null) |
| 2018-02-21 |  4 | (null) |     (null) |     (null) |    (null) |
| 2018-02-20 |  3 | (null) |     (null) |     (null) |    (null) |
| 2018-02-19 |  2 | (null) |     (null) |     (null) |    (null) |
| 2018-02-18 |  1 | (null) |     (null) |     (null) |    (null) |
| 2018-02-15 |  5 | (null) |     (null) |     (null) |    (null) |
| 2018-02-14 |  4 | (null) |     (null) |     (null) |    (null) |
| 2018-02-13 |  3 | (null) |     (null) |     (null) |    (null) |
| 2018-02-12 |  2 | (null) |     (null) |     (null) |    (null) |
| 2018-02-11 |  1 | (null) |     (null) |     (null) |    (null) |
| 2018-02-08 |  5 | (null) |     (null) |     (null) |    (null) |
| 2018-02-07 |  4 | (null) |     (null) |     (null) |    (null) |
| 2018-02-06 |  3 | (null) |     (null) |     (null) |    (null) |
| 2018-02-05 |  2 | (null) |     (null) |     (null) |    (null) |
```

Comment: Great idea, to create a dynamic tble with the expected dates and join it with the actual ones. I'll mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare  @StartDate  DateTime  ='20180301' 
Declare  @EndDate  DateTime    ='20180330' 

DECLARE @NotVisitedPatients table ( idPatient Int  ,Sday INT , Vdate Date,Vday int ,WeekNumber INT )
DECLARE @WeekNumber table ( Id Int identity (1,1) ,WeekNumber INT )

INSERT INTO @WeekNumber
SELECT  distinct
DATEPART(Week ,V.[VDate])
FROM [dbo].[tblVisits] V 
inner  join [dbo].[tblScheduledOrder] S  on V.idPatient =  S.idPatient
where V.[VDate] between @StartDate and @EndDate 

declare @Total int = (select Max(Id) from  @WeekNumber)
declare @count  int =1
declare @week  int = 0 

WHILE (@Total >= @count)
BEGIN  
set  @week =(select WeekNumber from @WeekNumber where  id =@count)
print @week
INSERT INTO @NotVisitedPatients
           (idPatient
           ,Sday
           ,Vdate
           ,Vday
           ,WeekNumber)
select distinct  S.idPatient ,S.Sday ,null,null, @week from tblScheduledOrder S
where  S.idPatient  not in (select V.idPatient   from tblVisits V  
where DATEPART(Week ,V.[VDate]) = @week)
set @count =@count +1 
END

select  idPatient   ,Sday , Vdate,Vday  ,WeekNumber  from @NotVisitedPatients
Union 
SELECT  distinct S.idPatient
       ,S.Sday  
       ,V.[VDate]      
      , DATEPART(DW ,V.[VDate]) As VDay    
      , DATEPART(Week ,V.[VDate]) As WeekNumber
  FROM [dbo].[tblVisits] V 
  inner  join [dbo].[tblScheduledOrder] S  on V.idPatient =  S.idPatient
where V.[VDate] between @StartDate and @EndDate
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is how to get this all into one result set, isn't it? Instead of using the application for that, use a temporary table to store the loop results. Then have the application pick up it's data from the temporary table. (You could use a regular table, or a #TempTable. You just need a place to park your intermediate data sets.)

```
DECLARE @tblPlaceHolder TABLE (
  idPatient BIGINT,
  VDay TINYINT,
  SDay TINYINT,
  Week SMALLINT);

<Your existing loop code except add this:  >
  INSERT INTO @tblPlaceHolder (
    idPatient,
    VDay,
    SDay,
    Week)
  SELECT
    Visits.idPatient,
    Visits.VDay,
    tblScheduledOrder.SDay,
    @WEEK AS Week    --<-------Addition to SELECT
  FROM
    tblScheduledOrder
    LEFT OUTER JOIN....

<The rest of your loop code>

    SELECT @WEEK = @WEEK - 1
END  

SELECT 
  idPatient,
  SDay,
  VDay
FROM 
  @tblPlaceHolder
ORDER BY
  Week DESC, --Not needed in the result set. Just to sort by.
  SDay,
  idPatient;
```

Comment: There's almost never one best way to do anything. But if nothing else is working for you, and this is working, then it might be a good enough way.